# Joomla! event for plugin edit page / onPluginEdit?

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0, joomla-extensions

I have a system plugin and on its configuration page I'm adding some styles/scripts like this:

```
function onAfterDispatch(){

    // some magic here....

    if($app->isAdmin()){
        # Get current component & its layout
        $option = JRequest::getVar('option');
        $layout = JRequest::getVar('layout');

        # Add some styling on plugin's edit page
       if($option == 'com_plugins' && $layout == 'edit') $doc->addStyleSheet($mediapath . '/themes/mystyle.css');
    }
}
```

... which works great!

But, if the plugin is disabled the onAfterDispatch is not called and mystyle.css and other scripts that I wish to add on this page won't be loaded.

So, is there a method of doing this when plugin is disabled? I need some event like onPluginEdit or even onPluginSave...

*This is a plugin for J! 2.5 / 3.x

Comment: Why are your stylesheet and script files tied to the plugin if they're loaded regardless?

Comment: My stylesheet and script are not loaded automatically and I need them only on plugin's edit page. I have a lot of checkboxes and from my stylesheet i'm grouping them in columns and with some js script i'll try to handle unchecked checkbox fields.

Comment: Just on a side note, if you're plugin is for Joomla 2.5 **and** 3.x, I would suggest you perform a version check, then use `JRequest` for 2.5 and `JInput` for 3.x ;)

Comment: As described http://docs.joomla.org/Retrieving_request_data_using_JInput I can use JInput from 2.5+. Thanks for the suggestion, some other user told me same thing on google groups.